# setState override existing state

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function to set state:

```
const [study, setStudy] = useState(defaultState)

const setValue = (section, key, value) => {
  setStudy({...study, [section]: {...study[section], [key]: value}})
}
```

But for some reason it keeps overriding the existing state, what am I doing wrong?

I call the function like this:

```
setValue('company', 'name', 'test')
setValue('property', 'state', 'test2')
setValue('property', 'address', 'test3')
```

Structure of data:

```
const defaultState: StudyData = {
  client: {},
  company: {},
  property: {},
  study: {}
}
```

Comment: can you please share structure of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with multiple state-updating events, the standard behavior for React is to batch them. The state-updating method does not immediately update the state of the component, React just puts the update in queue to be processed later when event handling is complete. Changes are all flushed together at the end of the event and you don't see the intermediate state.

With batching, when the final set-state event executes, it has no recollection that the prevState has been updated (asynchrounous), which is why the final state appears to only reflect changes made by the last event.

Using a call-back function as the first argument for your `setStudy` method will  help you return the intermediate states and avoid the issue of batching. The updater function will loop through and shallowly merge all updated states with the previous component state. This ensures that we receive all state-updates and use all intermediate states before ultimately arriving at the final update.

```
  const setValue = (section, key, value) => {
    setStudy(study => {
      return {
        ...study,
        [section]: { ...study[section], [key]: value }
      };
    });
  };
```

Also see working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-tree-vqrz7

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that the study value you destruct is still an old version (a memoized one). It is the same between all `setValue` calls and thus your first two `setValue` calls do essentially nothing. If this is what's happening to you, the best way to fix it would be to give a callback function to `setStudy`. Any function given to a setter will get the absolute latest version of the state as parameter. Try it like this:

```
setStudy((latestStudy) => {
    return {
        ...latestStudy,
        [section]: {...latestStudy[section], [key]: value}
    }
});
```